# Auto populate fields from database in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

models.py

```
class InfraServiceInfo(db.Model):

    app_name = db.CharField(choices=VIEW_APP_CHOICES, max_length=1000)
    stack = db.CharField(max_length=1000)
    description = db.TextField('InfraServiceInfo', choices=VIEW_DESC_CHOICES)
```

A description is associated with every app_name in the InfraServiceInfo table. 
As app_name is a drop down list, when the selects a particular app_name the corresponding description associated with that app_name should be auto populated in the forms.

Example: app_name = "test", description = "testing"
 and app_name = "test2", description = "testing2".
When the user select test from drop downlist, the description should auto populate testing string. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to dedicate different `url` view to serve your selected `InfraServiceInfo`, where you can show the selected description.

Say your urls are like

url

```
url(r'^infraServiceInfo/$', 'myapp.views.infraServiceInfo', name='InfraServiceInfo'),
url(r'^infraServiceInfo/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', 'myapp.views.infraServiceInfo_detail', name='InfraServiceInfo_detail'),
```

And in your `infraServiceInfo_detail`

```
def infraServiceInfo_detail(request, app_name):

    description = InfraServiceInfo.objects.get(app_name=app_name).description
    app_names = InfraServiceInfo.objects.values_list('app_name', flat=True)
    return render(request, 'your_render.html', {'description': description, 'app_names': app_names})
```